# Display GeoServer's UTFGrid output in OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, utfgrid

[GeoServer added UTFGrid output](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/pull/1357) for vector features starting [from the 2.9-beta version](http://geoserver.org/release/dev/). It is implemented [as a WMS service output format](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/outputformats.html?highlight=utfgrid).

After installing GeoServer 2.9-beta, adding a datastore with a PostGIS connection and publishing a layer that contains vector features, I can click the `WMS UTFGrid` entry from the available formats list on the Layer Preview page in the admin UI and indeed get a UTFGrid representation of my data displayed in the browser.

How can I now integrate this as a UTFGrid layer into OpenLayers 3? The only resource that I could find on this topic is [this official example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/tileutfgrid.html). However, it uses [ol.source.TileUTFGrid](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/apidoc/ol.source.TileUTFGrid.html) as the layer's source and passes a URL which ends in `.json`. GeoServer, however, publishes a `WMS` URL which expects further parameters such as `request`, `bbox` etc.

Simply passing the URL generated by the Layer Preview page gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` in the browser's console.

What would be the correct way to include GeoServer's UTFGrid output as a layer?

Answer (score 1):

The URL you pass to `ol.source.TileUTFGrid` is a metadata url in [TileJSON](https://github.com/mapbox/tilejson-spec) format, which will be requested through JSONP. Not sure if GeoServer can answer that. Then, tile URLs use an XYZ template, which GeoServer could provide through its integrated GeoWebCache, if that has support for TileJSON already.

That said, the current implementation of `ol.source.TileUTFGrid` is not perfectly suited for use with GeoServer. It would have to be made more flexible in terms of configuration options.

Comment: Okay, I see. Do you know another way how I could get UTFGrid data from PostGIS in a format that is supported by OpenLayers 3? Is this what [this approach with Mapnik and TileStache](http://blog.perrygeo.net/2012/02/24/utfgrids-with-openlayers-and-tilestache/) is about?

Comment: GeoServer can also offer regular 256x256 UTFGrid tiles via its WMTS endpoint. There is also a pull request adding WMS/UTFGrid support to OL2, but it got no attention (I guess OL2 is jus not supported anymore) https://github.com/openlayers/ol2/pull/1486

Comment: Thanks for confirming Andrea. So to make OpenLayers 3 work with GeoServer, all we'd need is an alternate way to specify the layer configuration (i.e. a local TileJSON object instead of requesting it through JSONP).

Comment: Pull request created: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/5120.

Comment: Does anybody know how to properly set up GeoServer to provide the required WMTS endpoint that matches the example from the pull request? I have the assumption that this is not activated by default.

Comment: @Dirk - You can enable utfgrid for WMTS in the Tile Caching tab on GeoServer (Data > Layers > {Layer Name} > Tile Caching - select application/json;type=utfgrid). You will also have to remove the $ signs from the URLs in the example on the pull request.

Answer (score 1):

Hav a look at all these URLs

GetFeatureInfo from TileUTFGrid with XYZ based tileJSON source

GetFeatureInfo from TileUTFGrid with WMS based tileJSON source

using OpenLayers-3.21.0

http://jsfiddle.net/mmsmdali/73pgge4z

http://jsfiddle.net/mmsmdali/bc8da561