# Consuming GeoServer UTFGrid output in OpenLayers 3 ol.source.TileUTFGrid results in error processing response object

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, web-mapping, openlayers-2

GeoServer now supports UTFGrid outputs for layer services.  This is great however the support for consuming them seems incomplete in OpenLayers 3. I set up a simple map to attempt this but can't get it to work. The issue seems similar to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186282/display-geoservers-utfgrid-output-in-openlayers-3) however I have done the steps recommended and am still getting the same error.

Here are some details:

I'm making a request in OpenLayers 3 like this:

```
var geoserverGrid = new ol.source.TileUTFGrid({
        tileJSON: {
            "jsonp": true,
             "attribution": "",
            "bounds": [-180, -85.05112877980659, 180, 85.05112877980659],
            "grids": ["http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=topp:states&styles=&bbox=-124.73142200000001,24.955967,-66.969849,49.371735&width=768&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/json;type=utfgrid"],
            "maxzoom": 8,
            "minzoom": 0,
            "scheme": "xyz",
            "tilejson": "2.0.0",
            "tiles": ["http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=topp:states&STYLE=_null&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:4326&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:4326:{z}&TILEROW={y}&TILECOL={x}&FORMAT=image/png"],
            "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "jsonp": true,
  });
var geoserverGridLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({source: geoserverGrid});
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
         geoserverGridLayer
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  });
```

The response from GeoServer looks like this:

```
{
"grid": [
"                                                                                                              
     !!                                                                             
",
"      
####################$$$%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&!!!!!!!!                                                                                            
",
"    
...... I CUT THIS RESPONSE OFF TO SAVE SPACE IN THIS POST
```

The error that is thrown in the console is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token:
```

Which on closer instpection is pointing at

```
"grid":
```

For clarity's sake I looked at the layer source response from [this official OpenLayers 3 UTFGrid example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/tileutfgrid.html) and noticed that the UTF object is NOT wrapped in a "grid" property. In fact, it looks a lot different.  You can see the MapBox request [here](https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.geography-class.json?secure&access_token=sk.eyJ1IjoianVzdGlubGV3aXMiLCJhIjoiY2l0YnlwcmJ0MDllcDJ0czZocWk2cDZvMiJ9.M0sqfzuX9MulN5eq2bRZOQ).

What I am seeing from these two responses is a completely different format being used for ol.source.TileUTFGrid.

In [the question I mentioned above](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186282/display-geoservers-utfgrid-output-in-openlayers-3) @ahocevar said:

> the current implementation of ol.source.TileUTFGrid is not perfectly suited for use with GeoServer. It would have to be made more flexible in terms of configuration options.

I had hopped that @ahocevar response would be fixed with the pull request mentioned in that same question but It appears that is not the case. It's very possible that I am doing something wrong.  Can anybody verify that I am indeed setting up this layer correctly and that this is (as presumed) an issue where OpenLayers 3 just doesn't support GeoServers UTFGrid output format yet?